# Elliptic PDE regularity

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I have $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is bounded which solves some elliptic PDE of the form: 
$$-\Delta u + h(u) = f$$ in $\Omega$, where $f \in L^2(\Omega)$

$$u = 0$$ on $\partial\Omega$, say.

How do I get an estimate for $\lVert \Delta u \rVert_{L^2(\Omega)}$? Surely I can't even write that because $u$ is only in $H^1$? But apparently I can. Can I just do something with the strong form?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Isn't the Sobolev norm $$\left\Vert \phi\right\Vert _{H^{1}}^{2}=\left\Vert \phi\right\Vert _{L^{2}}^{2}+\left\Vert \nabla\phi\right\Vert _{L^{2}}^{2} ?$$ so surely if $\Delta u\in H^{1}$  then $\Delta u\in L^{2}$.

Comment: @Pox but how is $\Delta u \in H^1$?

Comment: ...ignore me, I thought you wrote $\Delta u$ is in $H^1$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo suppose that $h \equiv 0.$

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: If $h \equiv 0$, then the problem is trivial - just $H^2$ estimates for the Poisson problem. In general, it depends on $h$.